# Is it a Peace Lily and can I rescue this?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, pests

Bought two of these (Peace Lily?) for the bedrooms but this one is in trouble - what can I do to rescue it? Am thinking it has been overwatered by house sitter during my absence and seems also to have contracted a ‘pest’! Any help and advice greatly appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvcSs.jpg)

Comment: It's not a peace lily, possibly an aglaonema, same Arum family